# How to close a pdf file using python

Tags: python, pdf, subprocess

I'm trying to close a pdf file using a Tkinter button but I can't find any suitable solution for my problem. I'm using a raspberry pi with Raspbian operating system

I've tried the `kill()` function but my pdf file is not closing.

Here's my code to open a pdf file

```
class Thesis():
   self.packet = io.BytesIO()
   self.can = canvas.Canvas(self.packet, pagesize = letter)
   self.can.drawString(250,250, "Hello World")
   self.can.save()

   self. packet.seek(0)
   self.new_pdf = PdfFileReader(self.packet)
   self. existing_pdf = PdfFileReader(open("Sample.pdf", "rb"))
   self.existing _pdf.decrypt('')
   self.output = PdfFileWriter()

   self.page = self.existing_pdf.getPage(0)
   self.page.mergePage(self.new_pdf.getPage(0))

   self.outpute.addPage(self.page)
   self.outputStream = open("destination.pdf", "wb")
   output.write(self.outpuStream)


   self.opener ="open" if sys.platform == "darwin"else "xdg-open"
   subprocess.call([self.opener, "destination.pdf"])

   #create print button
   self.print_root = Toplevel()
   self.print_root.geometry("+910+635")

   self.print_button = Button(self.print_root, text ="Print", width = 10, height = 5, command = self.print_form)
   self.print_button.pack()

   def print_form(self):

      #code to close a pdf file after clicking a print button.
      self.filename = "/home/pi/Thesis/barangay_certification_result.pdf"
      self.p = subprocess.Popen("exec " + filename, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
      self.p.kill()
```

all I have to do is to totally close the pdf file, completely terminated.

Comment: Your opener is a proxy that calls an other process. You will have to kill (or better terminate) that other process.

Comment: Hi sir, can you give me an idea of how can I do that? I tried `self.opener.kill()` but my error is `'str' object has no attribute kill`. Should I try other code to open a pdf?

Comment: Naming a user-defined function `print()` is horrible. What’s up with the weird indentation starting at `self.print_root...`? Can you share more of your code? See: [mcve].

Comment: Hi sir @AlexanderCécile, I'm so sorry about that. I edited the indentation and changed the print() function. I edited my post and try some solution I found here in StackOverflow but It's not working, don't have any error either.

Comment: @tintinie So it just doesn’t close the pdf, no crash or errors? Also, can you share more of your code ([mcve]) so that people can run and debug it themselves? :)

Comment: @AlexanderCécile yes that's my only problem. I edited my code and put all my code including the reading and writing a PDFfile. Thank You!